# What other words than 奥 exist for places of reveration?

Tags: vocabulary, word, terminology

奥(ao4) denotes a place inside a house,where offerings to one's ancestors are put. It is located in the south western corner of the house.

Beside this term, are there further words like this?

Comment: Are you asking for a list of obscure terms or any term that describe spiritually sacred place?

Comment: Sacred places, but if you know about a list of obscure terms please post.

Comment: If you want I can change the question into obscure terms.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

四隅（four corners of a room）

宧（yí ／ ㄧˊ）：室內東北角（northeastern corner）

窔（yào ／ ㄧㄠˋ ）同“穾”：室內東南角（southeast corner）

奥（ào ／ ㄠˋ）：室內西南角（southwest corner）

屋漏（wū lòu ／ ㄨ ㄌㄡˋ）：室內西北角（northwest corner）

Comment: How come northwest corner never got its own single character?